# Changing html element content when checkbox is checked not working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, checked

I'm trying to figure out how to change the content of my `<p>` tag once I click the checkbox.

I tried doing it with a if-statement, but nothing seems to happen.

HTML:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>


<div class="pricing-box pricing-box-active" id="basic">
    <h2>Basic</h2>
    <div class="price">
        <p>$199.99</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var inputBtn = document.querySelector("input")

if(inputBtn.checked === true) {
    console.log("Toggle is checked")

    var basic = document.querySelector("#basic .price p"); 
    basic.textContent = "$19.99";   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  if statement should be  in a  call back  function, when  checkbox  get some changes. Like `inputBtn.addEventListener("change", ()=>{})`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you know how I can revert the content back to $199.99 soon as I uncheck again? Right now it stays $19.99

Comment: You will need  to add else statement.